# How to restart binance threaded websocket after losing internet connection

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

Is there a way to automatically restart binance `ThreadedWebsocketManager` when the internet connection was lost?

Comment: @samuehertrich  if you have solved the issue could you please provide some code for the same.I am also struggling with this as i have no background in async programming and it will probably take some time to figure it out.

Comment: @pppp_prs Unfortunately I haven't tried it yet but as soon as I have the code I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, as python-binance sdk is listing it as one of its [features](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#features):

> Websocket handling with reconnection and multiplexed connections

Since they are an open-source project, maybe having a look at their source code be helpful.

P.S. As the question author asked for more info: I searched github repository of python-binance for the phrase **reconnect** and the first result [**pointed me**](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/f434509905e5c41cfc9739dd12ca7c5fde972549/binance/streams.py) to where you expect.

In their latest version(which now reads 0.7.10) they have defined a complete class for this purpose, namely `class ReconnectingWebsocket` based on python **asyncio** module. But in the version that i am accustomed to(0.7.5) they were using `class ReconnectingClientFactory` from the **twisted** package to accomplish this.

... And to see how they have used this class, Just search their repository recursively until arriving to the point that they start to use their stuff rather than defining more stuff!

In this case(Version 0.7.10) the next phrase to search for is  **ReconnectingWebsocket** which brings up declaration of `class KeepAliveWebsocket(ReconnectingWebsocket):`. One more search to see what are they doing with `KeepAliveWebsocket` shows [**this line**](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/f434509905e5c41cfc9739dd12ca7c5fde972549/binance/streams.py#L334) in the body of the method `_get_account_socket` of `class BinanceSocketManager` so every time you are calling `get_account_socket` you are implicitly implementing the functionality of `ReconnectingWebsocket` to enjoy auto reconnecting feature of python-binance.

Comment: Can't find something like that in the source code. Can somebody show me where it is?

Comment: @samuelhertrich I've edited my answer to add more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I just need to figure out where to put this into my code...

Comment: @samuelhertrich, I've added my idea about how they are using the  ReconnectingWebsocket  class.